# Text isn't updating in the file

Tags: python, file-handling

```
import os
from time import sleep
import maskpass
password_check = False
re_enter_pass = True
while password_check == False:
    while re_enter_pass == True:
        user_name = str(input("Hello person, what would you like your username to be? \n"))
        password = maskpass.askpass(mask="")
        if len(user_name) and len(password) != 0:
            f = open("User_Data.txt","a") 
        if len(password) < 8:
            print("Please enter a password with 8 minimum letters.\n")
        else:
            f.write(f"{user_name}; {password}\n")
            print("Password stored.")
            sleep(2)
            os.system('cls')
            sleep(2)
            re_enter = input("Would you like to enter a new password? (Y/N)\n")
            if re_enter == "Y":
                re_enter_pass = True
                os.system('cls')
            elif re_enter == "N":
                re_enter_pass = False
                password_check = True
                break
```

Why isn't the username and password variables updating in the text file?

It was previously working but I feel like I messed up with the while loops. I was expecting it to append the username and the password in the text file using this format "{username}; {password}".

Comment: You should close the file.  It might not be the issue, but it is good practice.  If it is not closed before the program exits, the write buffer might be flushed and you will lose what was in the buffer.

Comment: If user answers Y to "Would you like to enter a new password? (Y/N)" he also has to re-enter a username. That makes no sense (to me). Why sleep()? Why (non-portable) cls? What if the username already exists in the output file?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should be thinking about is the format of your data file. In your code (if it was working as intended) your file could have multiple occurrences of a username. You could either user a formal database or, much simpler, a JSON.

You would start by loading existing file content. If the file doesn't exist just work with an empty dictionary.

When user input is complete, just dump the dictionary (as JSON) to the data file.

Validate the inputs as you go along. Use *while* loops.

Here's a fully working example of how you could approach this:

```
from maskpass import askpass
from json import load, dump

DB = "User_Data.json"
MINPW = 8

def load_content():
    try:
        with open(DB, "r") as data:
            return load(data)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}

def dump_content(content):
    with open(DB, "w") as data:
        dump(content, data)

data = load_content()

while user := input("Input username (<return> to finish): "):
    while len(pwd := askpass()) < MINPW:
        print(f"Password must be at least {MINPW} characters")
    data[user] = pwd

dump_content(data)

for k, v in data.items():
     print(f"{k}: {v}")
```